# Chrome on Android sets video currentTime only to 0 or half length

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, video

I'm making a video player and testing it on Nexus 7. Besides a bug when my progress bar with dynamically changing width would blink when I play a video for the second time (wtf really), I can't make it seek to a particular point of time in the video.
So the code is pretty basic,

```
<video width="640" height="360">
    <source src="output2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
```

The video is 16 seconds long and if I do

```
myVideo.pause();
myVideo.currentTime = 5; 
myVideo.play();
myVideo.currentTime; // shows 5 in console but does not work, skips to 8s
```

When I set the current time to 5, it jumps straight to 8.6 or something. And if I set it to 0, it jumps to 0. These seem to be only 2 points where I can jump to. Tested on normal Chrome, works fine, and on iPad simulator as well. Dolphin has the same bug...

Could somebody test on their Android device pls? 
My server is fine since normal Chrome works ok.

Demo: http://lowrider.comlu.com/normal_video.html 
Clicking on 5s brings me to 6.8s on Android device... it's ok but the other video will only go to 8s. I think it's something to do with encoding.

Cheers.

Comment: do you have a test URL we can hit that shows this?

Comment: I've seen this problem occur on YouTube in a WebView based browser, and the only way I have been able to resolve it is to reload the page. It's definitely a problem with the Android WebView.

Comment: ok here's the URL http://lowrider.comlu.com/normal_video.html
if you test it on Android as I do, clicking on 5s will take you to 6.80s and on 10 to about 11s, better than what I'm working with but still makes the point.